# How to use unique symbol as object property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, symbols

I need to use `unique symbol` in TypeScript in order to be able to dynamically compose an object literal. If I use regular `symbol`, I get this error:

> A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

However, I'm not sure how to use `unique symbol` as an object property.

```js
const bar: unique symbol = Symbol("bar"); // This is fine

interface MyInterface {
    readonly id: unique symbol;
}

const foo: MyInterface = {
    id: Symbol("id"),
};

// Error: Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'unique symbol'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's either me, or handling symbols in TypeScript is VERY lacking. I encounter new problems all the time.

Comment: Perhaps you should show how you are creating the new object using the symbol as a key.

Comment: @kelsny I have a quite complex use case, I will consider creating a question for it.

Comment: Seems like your actual problem is whatever's causing the "A computed property name in an interface" error, but you haven't shown it so I'm not sure. Could you provide a [mre] of whatever is doing that so we can suggest alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this behavior lies in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html#unique-symbol) (as most things are :p):

> To enable treating symbols as unique literals a special type `unique symbol` is available. `unique symbol` is a subtype of `symbol`, and are produced only from calling `Symbol()` or `Symbol.for()`, or from explicit type annotations. This type is **only allowed on const declarations and readonly static properties**, and *in order to reference a specific unique symbol, you’ll have to use the typeof operator*.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to achieve what you are looking for. Trying to extract the symbol into its own `const` declaration yields a different error:

```
const id: unique symbol = Symbol("id");

const foo: MyInterface = {
    id,
//  ~~
// Type 'typeof id' is not assignable to type 'typeof foo.id'.(2322)
};
```

I guess it's because the `unique symbol` type of `id` is unique, it isn't assignable to the `unique symbol` type that `MyInterface` expects... It appears that this is the intended behavior of unique symbols. See [ms/TS#23388](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23388), an exact copy of your question.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4C4YFcwEsCO6CmMEAngLZwgA2MAvDAMpkWUAUARIkmwJQDcMAegEwAKgAssEGJJgAzLGHwBYAFCqFUfElkJghALLEAkmE3bdhAN6qYtmEnwIAJuErFpTtJlwEiTKryqAL6qqqCQsFieGNh4hCTkVLQM-qxsUTyBairh0HIgIGiGJmY6esnWKnYeADTBWUA)

---

Of course, I could be proven wrong and maybe there is a way you could get this to work.

Comment: I'm trying to just have an interface of specific symbols mapped to specific types. Couldn't do it for `Map`, because `Map` is very limited in TypeScript. Can't do it for plain objects neither?

Comment: It appears to be the case. However, you could always ignore the compiler and abstract away the lie you tell it: https://tsplay.dev/w1Q42w

Comment: Sure, but I wanted to do this in order to achieve type safety of the value anyway, so it's of no use to cheat here.

Answer (score 0):

To use `unique symbol` as a property, you need

```
const bar: unique symbol = Symbol("bar"); // This is fine

interface MyInterface {
  readonly [bar]: 123;
}

const foo: MyInterface = {
  [bar]: 123
}
```

It has no difference of string literals

```
interface MyInterface {
  readonly "bar": 123;
}

const foo: MyInterface = {
  "bar": 123
}
```